# KeyCloak file keycloak-server.json doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, server, keycloak

I'm setting up a KeyCloak server and want to use MongoDB as specified in the  docs here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/1.9/server_installation_guide/topics/mongo.html


As the title suggests the keycloak-server.json(needed to configure KeyCloak for MongDB integration) doesn't exist in `…​/standalone/configuration` or any of the KeyCloak directories.

```
bramvanhoutte$ find ./  -name "*.json"
.//themes/keycloak-preview/account/resources/package-lock.json
.//themes/keycloak-preview/account/resources/package.json
.//themes/keycloak-preview/account/resources/tslint.json
.//themes/keycloak-preview/account/resources/tsconfig.json
.//themes/keycloak/common/resources/lib/angular/version.json
.//themes/keycloak/common/resources/lib/angular/errors.json
```

I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what...

Comment: Are you using Keycloak 1.9?

Comment: Are you sure you want follow this path. Keycloak 1.9 is very old (current version is 4.5.0) and MongoDB is deprecated and will not be supported anymore (http://blog.keycloak.org/2017/02/removing-mongo-support-from-keycloak.html).

Comment: Project has been put on pause. I will have to look into using 4.5 and a different data storage system.